# History and meaning of the word "clientelist" as in "clientelist politics"

Tags: meaning, etymology

In relation to news reports about modern Greece I see the term "clientelist politics" which I assume to refer to some sort of corruption. In order to learn more I looked up *clientelist* in the OED only to find it isn't there.

> What is the history of the word *clientelist* and what exactly is its
>   modern meaning?

Comment: A Google search comes up with a wide range of resources. [Like this](https://www.google.fr/search?q=clientelism&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ETKWVaPLOcKnU52igAg) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clientelism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clientelism#Origins) is a practice which originated in Ancient Rome. *"Clientela"* was the network of people connected to the persons in power:

> - ***is the exchange of goods and services for political support, often involving an implicit or explicit quid-pro-quo.*** It is a political system at the heart of which is an asymmetric relationship between groups of political actors described as patrons and clients and political parties.

The origin:

> - ***of the practice has been traced to ancient Rome. Here relationships between the patron (patronus) and client (cliens) were seen as crucial to understanding the political process***.
> - ***While the obligations between these were mutual, the key point is they were hierarchical. These relationships might be best viewed not as an entity but rather as a network (clientela), with the patronus himself perhaps being obligated to someone of greater power, and the cliens perhaps having more than one patron***. These extensions increase the possibilities of conflicting interests arising.
> - ***While the familia was the basic unit underlying Roman society, the interlocking networks (clientela) acted as restrictions on their autonomy but allowed a more complex society to develop***. Historians of the late medieval period evolved the concept into bastard feudalism. There is, as is usual, ambiguity in the use of political terminology and the terms "clientelism," the "patron-client relationship," "patronage" and the political machine are sometimes used to described similar or related concepts.

Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

"Clientilism" is a social or political system based on patronage.  You may check [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clientelism).